# How to calculate mask-image gradient consistency loss in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient, loss-function

I want to create custom loss function as described in this article [Real-time deep hair matting on mobile devices](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.07168.pdf). I have implemented it in TF2.0 (Google Colab) it worked with no errors. However I don't see any improvement in the accuracy as described in the article(1% improvement). I am not sure that my implementation on calculating mask-image consistency loss(Lc) is correct. Please see my code below. I had to add 1e-30 to mask gradient magnitude because loss became nan.  Can anyone see an issue to implement this function?

```
def custom_loss(input_img):

    def Loss(y_true, y_pred):

        L = tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=False)

        input_img_gray = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(input_img)

        Iy, Ix = tf.image.image_gradients(input_img_gray)

        Mys, Mxs = tf.image.image_gradients(y_pred)


        Mx_pow = tf.math.square(Mxs)
        My_pow = tf.math.square(Mys)
          
        M_mag = tf.sqrt(tf.math.add(Mx_pow,My_pow) + 1e-30 ) 
    
        M_magsum = tf.math.reduce_sum(M_mag, axis=None) 

        inner_form = 1 - (tf.math.pow((Ix * Mxs + Iy * Mys),2))
  
        Lc = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.multiply(M_mag,inner_form))
        Lc = tf.math.divide(Lc,M_magsum)
    
       loss =  tf.math.add(L, (0.5 * Lc))
    
    return loss

return Loss
```

[image]